# How to record audio from both headphone speaker ( internal audio ) and mic simultaneously in android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, audio-processing

I am trying to create a Karaoke live app, where the host can start a karaoke session by playing a karaoke video on phone and sings along using his headphones and I will be streaming the screen with audio using [OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/basic-video-chat/) SDK. the problem faced is only the mic audio is getting picked up but the audio from the karaoke song is not getting recorded as its playing in headphone speaker.

- How can I merge both headphone speaker audio and mic audio together and record it has one.